# Get request fragment inside Laravel middleware

Tags: php, laravel, request

from the middleware `handle(Request $request ...) { .. }` how do you get the request fragment of Laravel `Request $request`

i want to get the fragment of `dd($request);`

result is something like this.

```
Request {#42 ▼
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  ...
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/admin/ar/edit/1"
  #requestUri: "/emt/admin/ar/edit/1"
  #baseUrl: "/emt"
  ...
}
```

from the result above. i want to get the `#` in the result. i tried

```
echo $request->pathInfo; <-- null

echo $request['pathInfo']; <-- null

echo $request->get('pathInfo'); <-- null

echo $request->pathInfo(); <-- error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
echo $request->getPathInfo();
```

also you can use:

```
$request->getRequestUri();
$request->getBaseUrl();
$request->getBasePath();
$request->getUri();
$request->getContentType();
$request->getContent();
$request->getClientIp();
$request->getAcceptableContentType();
$request->getCharsets();
$request->getClientIps();
...[AND MANY MORE]
```

Comment: wow. those magic method works. thank you! i wonder why the other getters are not working.

Answer (score 0):

try `$request->getContent(`), `json_decode($request->getContent())` for a better manipulation

Comment: thank you but $request->getContent() is still empty or null

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$request->path()
```

[As defined in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#request-path-and-method)

Comment: thank you but $request->path() returns null or empty still. maybe because im calling this inside the middleware??

Comment: Can you please add the whole method that you are trying to get the details within?

Comment: hi Josh, thank you. it is just a default middleware `handle()` method. i just added the `use Illuminate\Http\Request` above it. any specific details you want to know?

Comment: Helps to diagnose the problem!

Comment: Give me a minute.